# Excel: How to convert Calendar Days to Workdays

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Example of the Table:
[image: Example of the Table]

Hello! I have to convert a table that displays shipping times from A to B. A shipment can leave at any day Mon - Fri. And it displays the Lead Time of the shipment in days. The Rows represents Different Countries and Zones where a shipment can travel

A typical value in the table is between 1 - 16.

EDIT:

The Table data is displayed in the idea that if a Shipment leaves on Monday it takes 7 calendar days to reach its destination. So what I would need is a way to subtract weekends from the Raw day count.

For example the First **Monday** value takes a week to reach it's destination. I would need the "7" to not count the weekend. So it would be "5" workdays.

Comment: If I'm not wrong then you want to find out Working days excluding holidays !!

Comment: Could you please also share desired output? Do you need to consider (public) holidays too, or only weekends?

Comment: No need to consider holidays. Only Weekends.

Comment: @AlexKangaroo,, i think your sample data needs some modifications since Calender Days belongs to Month, for example `Jan has 31 Calender days` & `Weekends+Holidays` should be `subtracted from Calender days` to get `Workdays` !!

Comment: @RajeshS The Table data is displayed in the idea that if a Shipment leaves on Monday it takes 7 calendar days to reach its destination. The Rows represents Different Countries and Zones where a shipment can travel.

So what I would need is a way to subtract weekends from the Raw day count.

Comment: @AlexKangaroo, in that case you need Start & End Date of Shipments. Suppose shipment starts on Monday then better input Date & apply Format to get Weekdays Name and get Column Total for Weekdays to get Workdays for the Month for Monday and others,, also you have more than 7 days in Monday Col like 10 !!

Comment: Do you mean that "Monday / 7" should give 5 or 9?

Comment: 1. Are you saying that if something ships on Monday with a 7 day lead time, the 7 days will include a weekend, so it will be 5 workdays?  2. How do you interpret 7 days lead time in terms of end date (if a shipment is on Tuesday, does 7 days equal the following Monday or Tuesday; how do you count the ship and deliver dates against the lead time)?  3. If a lead time ends on a Saturday or Sunday, what day is the delivery assumed to be for your calculations (that day, the following Monday, or something else)?

Comment: Please don't hide clarifications in comments, which are transient.  Edit the question to add the clarifications so current and future readers can find all of the relevant information.

Comment: You have not answered my questions 2 & 3 in the earlier comment, so the question cannot be reliably answered using any approach. You have accepted an answer, so that one apparently works for you (actually, it's flawed), but this won't be helpful to future readers without clarification because they won't understand how to apply it to their own problem. Please clarify the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added helper row on top of the original data, so you can use this formula to subtract weekends:
`=A3-INT((A3+A$1)/7)*2`

[image]

Comment: This appears to work for the example in the question, but check what happens with, for example, a lead time of 2 on a Friday.

Comment: @fixer1234 yes you're right if delivery happens on weekend then calculation might be incorrect. According to my understanding of the question it always done on workday.

Answer (score 1):

If you rework your table to somehow reveal actual **start** and **end** dates, you will have `NETWORKDAYS()` come in handy for calculating the day counts. So:

[image]

... here with C3 containing `=B3-A3` and D3 `=NETWORKDAYS(A3;B3)`
*(=Net Workdays)*

This will also allow for any number of days for the deliveries (as shown in the excel sheet!), and additionally allow to remove holidays by adding these to a list, with that list passed as an additional argument to `NETWORKDAYS()`

Comment: I understand this is the best way to get accurate data, but the source data for the Table is unfortunately out of my control. I will keep this in mind for the future projects. Thank you for the input.

Comment: =)  -- I wonder why you wouldn't be able to read the data (formulas on a secondary sheet probably) and create the table there, using the above. Create formulas that allows to replace the input data for a refreshed calculation?

Comment: @AlexKangaroo, you can get the calendar end date by adding the lead time (simple date addition since Excel dates are in units of days).  You can also derive the calendar start date.